# Subclassing application, Launching nested activities, and detect when last one has exit

Tags: android, android-activity, subclass, lifecycle

I'd like someone to help me with this question regarding an application lifecycle.

My App starts an activity **StoryActivity**, that can launch other instances of itself, so when the user presses the **BACK** button, returns to the previous StoryActivity.

I maintain a **cross-activity cache** in a static hashmap that I'd like to flush on the activity's **OnDestroy**, but only if this is **the last of my spawned activities**, i mean, only if the user has destroyed all the stacked (linked) stories and this is the only one left. Kind of an application shutdown.

Do I need to subclass Application, or what's the best practice for my intentions?

I'd like to avoid tracking myself the activity nesting if possible, relying on the android standard lifecycle as much as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why bother? Android will terminate your process sometime after the user is done with it, and your cache will go away at that point. And, if the user returns to your app before that happens, having flushed this cache means that now the user has to wait for you to load the data again. What is the user gaining?

Comment: What's the reason behind manually disposing of the cache? Do you need to do some flushing to the DB?

Comment: @Commonsware hi, I readed your excellent answer in other post about the subject and it has helped me a lot to understand things. My problem is..  I think I'm running into fragmentation issues... My app was sweet until I implemented a small LRUCACHE(3mb) to store just tiny thumbnails the different widgets use. I already have a L2 cache on sdcard. What happens now is I end up with outOfMemory errors I think bc fragmentation, failing to allocate 2mb when there are like 15 free on the heap. ... continues ....

Comment: .... this happens imho because the static LRU cache is holding a lot of pieces (they were thumbnails, so maybe there are like 200) from here and there, from different activities that are no longer alive. If I could dispose of those bitmaps, I think I'd solve straight the problem. The source of these problems is, the StoryActivities render heterogeneous slides into fragments, and all of them load a LOT of pics. I am constantly using and freeing a lot of memory, the tablet barely has capacity for 3 or 4 slides and the stories have typically hundreds.

Comment: If your problem is memory fragmentation, clearing your cache will not help, as Dalvik's garbage collector is non-compacting, so you will be as fragmented as before.

Comment: Well I sometimes run on the edge of the 48mb heap (my base heap requirement for a smooth experience guarantee). I think I did a decent job unbinding drawables, etc... between fragments that are detached, etc. ON a Galaxy-tab 1 I can sweep through 50 pages some of them with 15mb content and I managed to efficiently dispose stuff so there are no leaks, etc, because at the beginning it was terrible! Up to now I hadn't used the LRU cache, and the widgets used the sdcard as the only cache source...

Comment: .But as a test, I enabled a small LRU cache (L3) of 3Mb to hold only bitmaps of less than 150kb. Then I started to get OOM errors
(after heavy use). My reasoning is, those 3 mb of the LRU cache are terribly fragmented, because they are a lot of tiny pieces from very different places(even different fragments), and is probably why I get the OOM errors. Without LRU enabled, the memory usage is 3mb less, as expected, but I think the heap is freed and allocated more lineally, so the OOM errors don't happen. By manually trashing the cache on key points I might help the problem.

Comment: "By manually trashing the cache on key points I might help the problem" -- IMHO, you will not. Again, Dalvik's GC is non-compacting, meaning that once the heap is fragmented, it will remain fragmented. Your objective should be to avoid the heap fragmentation in the first place, such as by having a smaller in-memory cache (in terms of number of distinct bitmaps) and reusing bitmap memory via `inBitmap` on `BitmapOptions` wherever possible.

Comment: imBitmap!! hehe I discovered it this morning. I am still figuring out where and when to use it, I still don't really master 100% all the stuff going on under Android's hood, but try to catch up quickly!

Comment: D/dalvikvm(16848): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 102K, 29% free 34204K/48007K, paused 98ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(16848): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2789392-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(16848): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 29% free 34203K/48007K, paused 90ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(16848): Out of memory on a 2789392-byte allocation.    Does this have a solution other than to avoid fragmentation?